# Advice on multi lingual data storage

Tags: php, mysql, database, multilingual

I find myself struggling with the data model each time I want to do something with a multi lingual app using e.g. Google Maps. When a user for example searches for `Berlin` that's all fine when the user's language is set to English and German (and possibly more languages), but in Dutch `Berlin` translates to `Berlijn`. The same goes for `Munich` which translates to `München` in Dutch. And of course these are just two examples of many real world situations. In this illustration storage of a Hotel's location is used to demonstrate. So basically most of the times I end up with a schema like:

```
hotel
PK  id 
    other_properties

hotel_location
FK  hotel_id
FK  location_id

location
PK  id

location_translation
PK  id
FK  language_id
FK  location_id
    value

language
PK  id
    native_name
    system_name
```

Which gets populated like:

```
    HOTEL
    id      name                no_rooms    ...
    -------------------------------------------
    1       Radison Blu Hotel   16

    HOTEL_LOCATION
    hotel_id   location_id
    --------------------------------------------
    1          1

    LOCATION
    id
    --
    1

    LOCATION_TRANSLATION
    id      language_id     location_id     value
    ---------------------------------------------
    1       1               1               Berlin
    2       2               1               Berlijn
    3       3               1               Berlin

    LANGUAGE
    id      native_name     system_name
    -----------------------------------
    1       English         English
    2       Nederlands      Dutch
    3       Deutsch         German
```

But I always find this a bit complex in terms of how many tables are required and was wondering if you guys have better alternatives to store multi lingual data and keeping flexibility to add/remove supported languages.

Comment: As countries in the world hardly change, you don't need to store this in your database, but rather you can use ISO 3166-1 codes to recognize your country's translations. It's easier to inject this in your code from a config-file than to query it every time. If you do some clever searching online you can easily find fully translated lists for all these ISO's codes. That way you just load your country and it's translations once instead of querying it every compile.

Comment: Do you you really need the Language table ?

Comment: That's a good suggestion for the current project I'm working on. But in general; a hotel does not only lie in a country, but also a state, province, county, region, city. How would you suggest on that topic?

Comment: I guess the language table can be replaced with an in-code array or something similar (or defined constants..)

Comment: There are even district codes in ISO (https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:DE). You can find ISO and RFC for almost everything these days. Don't reinvent the wheel :).

Comment: Great addition, I didn't knew about your last comment.